# substract minutes from time using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, time

I need to substract some minutes from a spesific hour and show the output. For example, substract 10 minutes from 14:50 and show the output as 14:40.

How can i do that? I have tried datediff function but It doesn't work for that I guess. I also tried date.substract but I couldn't solve the issue with that either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I also tried date.substract but I couldn't solve the issue with that either" - care to elborate? BTW, I'd be surprised if a quick search didn't turn up hundreds of examples...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Dim datetime As DateTime = Date.Now
Dim newdatetime As DateTime = datetime.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0))
Console.WriteLine(newdatetime.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

Or this:

```
Dim datetime As DateTime = Date.Now
Dim newdatetime As DateTime = datetime.AddMinutes(-10)
Console.WriteLine(newdatetime.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

Or this:

```
Dim datetime As DateTime = Date.Now
Dim newdatetime As DateTime = datetime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
Console.WriteLine(newdatetime.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

The main point to take away is that if you subtract something from a date, the object itself is not updated, it just returns a new Date object with the result.

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMinutes()`

Comment: @Slaks Yeps, many ways to Rome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the timespan object.

Here is how to subtract 10 minutes from 14.50

```
Dim timeStart As New TimeSpan(14, 50, 0)
Dim timeToRemove As New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
Dim timeFinish As TimeSpan

timeFinish = timeStart.Subtract(timeToRemove)

Debug.Print(timeFinish.Hours.ToString + "-" + timeFinish.Minutes.ToString + "-" +         timeFinish.Seconds.ToString)
```